# What kind of effects-brushes where used in this picture?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, effects, brush, ink

[image]

I would really like to know how someone can achieve this type of illustration. What kind of effects or brushes were used?

Comment: Pen and paper...

Comment: Hi Maria and welcome to GDSE. A google image search revealed that the illustration is called "Haiku" and is made in 2014 by [Leonidas Giannakopoulos](https://leonidasgiannakopoulos.gr/). It's specified in his gallery that it's made with "ink on paper". It might be possible to develop a technique to do something similar digitally, but I don't think it's any easier than learning to draw this by hand.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, this is an all-manual technique.

There is an addon for Photoshop that does a similar effect.

You have to pay for the License.

http://www.pixeology.com/ArtisticHalftone/features.html

[image]